# Calling POST method from API controller

Tags: c#, api, post

I have an API controller named MyFIlesController.

In it, I have this method:

```
// POST api/myfiles
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

And here's how I call it with Fiddler:

```
POST
URL: `http://localhost:58075/api/myfiles`

-------------------------

Request Header:

User-Agent: Fiddler

Host: localhost:58075

Content-Type: application/json

Content-length: 18

-------------

Request body:
{"value": "asjkfsf"}
```

The method gets called, but value is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you showing a Fiddler-logged request that your code made or a request that you built in Fiddler?

Comment: Add [HttpPost] attribute to this method

Comment: @J0e3gan A request that I built in Fiddler.

Comment: '{"value": "asjkfsf"}'.length -> 20; not probably the reason of issue, but nevertheless.

Comment: So it sounds like the question is why `Post`'s caller is passing `null` for `value`, correct?

Comment: @Tommi The content length should be the length of {"value": "asjkfsf"} string?

Comment: AFAIK Content-Length should be your whole request body length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a class that corresponds to your JSON:

```
public class Test
{
    public string value{get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

And then change your Api-action:

```
// POST api/myfiles
public void Post([FromBody]Test value)
{

}
```

If you don't want to do that, just change the POST-body:

```
"somevalue"
```

**EDIT**: Added ID to the POST-payload.
Now your JSON should look like this:

```
{"value": "someval",
"ID": 1}
```

Comment: And what if the method has two input parameters? ([FromBody]string value, int id)

Comment: Do you want the id inside the JSON or as a Url-part?

Comment: I want the id to be in the Request Body.

Comment: Hmm so there isn't a way without craeting the new class?

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you're willing to pass it in the URL. Then you can just add the parameter to the action method and it will just work. But not through JSON no

Answer (score 1):

According to the MVC document http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1, Which exactly shows the same case as yours

Go to the **Sending Simple Types** part.

When you sending simple value, you need to

1. Use **FromBody** Attribute
2. the client needs to send the value with the following format:

   **=value**

   Specifically, the name portion of the name/value pair must be empty for a simple type.

Anyway, for further enhancement, you'd better use a complex type (an object) to accept the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from:

```
Request body:
{"value": "asjkfsf"}
```

To:

```
Request body:
"asjkfsf"
```

It will work for simple type with json format

Comment: And what if the method has two input parameters? ([FromBody]string value, int id)

Comment: @petko_stankoski: if you use id for just query, put it on querystring `?id=...`. For more, you really need a model

Comment: How can I use ?id= for POST method?

Comment: @petko_stankoski: just put on URL `URL: http://localhost:58075/api/myfiles?id=...`