# Json Value doesn't assign to the List [HttpPost]

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Since am new to web api, i am finding some difficulty to post json `List` to  Web API.

```
Json
[  
   {  
      "ItemId":20,
      "RegId":"VISIT0001778",
      "BLoadDetailId":"8/31/2018 12:28:10 PM",
      "OrderReferenceNo":null,
      "StartTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "InvalidItemMsg":"",
      "InvalidItemstatus":false,
      "BLoadingBay":"Chute 009",
      "BLoadingBayCode":null,
      "BLoadingBayID":7,
      "RFID":7123,
      "GangId":2,
      "BOrderTransfer":false,
      "BLoadedBags":0.0,
      "BRemainingBags":0.0,
      "BConversionValue":null,
      "WHid":2
   }
]
```

class :

```
 public class clsStartTimeUpdate
 {
     public int ItemId { get; set; }
     public string RegId { get; set; }
     public string BLoadDetailId { get; set; }
     public string OrderReferenceNo{ get; set; }
     public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
     public string InvalidItemMsg { get; set; }
     public bool InvalidItemstatus { get; set; }
     public string BLoadingBay { get; set; }
     public string BLoadingBayCode { get; set; }
     public int? BLoadingBayID { get; set; }
     public long? RFID { get; set; }
     public int? GangId { get; set; }
     public bool BOrderTransfer { get; set; }
     public decimal BLoadedBags { get; set; }
     public decimal BRemainingBags { get; set; }
     public string BConversionValue { get; set; }
     public int? WHid { get; set; }
 }
```

Json request

```
http://localhost:49290/api/config/Post?StartTimeDetails=[enter image description here][1][{%22ItemId%22:20,%22RegId%22:%22VISIT0001778%22,%22BLoadDetailId%22:%228/31/2018%2012:28:10%20PM%22,%22OrderReferenceNo%22:null,%22StartTime%22:%222001-01-01T00:00:00%22,%22InvalidItemMsg%22:%22%22,%22InvalidItemstatus%22:false,%22BLoadingBay%22:%22Chute%20009%22,%22BLoadingBayCode%22:null,%22BLoadingBayID%22:7,%22RFID%22:7123,%22GangId%22:2,%22BOrderTransfer%22:false,%22BLoadedBags%22:0.0,%22BRemainingBags%22:0.0,%22BConversionValue%22:null,%22WHid%22:2}]
```

Method WebAPI

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails)
{          
    return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);
}
```

result:

```
[{"ItemId":0,"RegId":null,"BLoadDetailId":null,"OrderReferenceNo":null,"StartTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","InvalidItemMsg":null,"InvalidItemstatus":false,"BLoadingBay":null,"BLoadingBayCode":null,"BLoadingBayID":null,"RFID":null,"GangId":null,"BOrderTransfer":false,"BLoadedBags":0.0,"BRemainingBags":0.0,"BConversionValue":null,"WHid":null}]
```

return result doesnot assign the values as in the Json.
May be this is a simple situation , but i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is the problem with the parameter into the method or the return value from it? Have you debugger the code to see if `StartTimeDetails` looks correctly to begin with?

Comment: Are you sure you *can* stuff json into the url like this? Wouldn't it be better to put the json content into the body of the request instead?

Comment: did you try [FromBody]

Comment: Json parameter is identified to the Web api correctly,though Json parameter values doesnot assign to the List (List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails) web api method

Comment: Code name Jack : yes. it returns Null in the                                                 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails)

Comment: which content type did u used `application-json` or `multipart/form-data` or `x-www-urlencoded`?

Comment: ershoaib : application-json

Comment: is @CodeNameJack, answer not help you bcoz its working good in my side also

Comment: content type is application/json

Comment: m asking above comment to @Udk, bcoz he not been satisfy with answer now

Comment: I followed the instructions, it works fine with POSTMAN, but when i include those json data in the URL it still returns the Null.

Comment: could u plz add your client side post method in question so I'll take a look on it?

Comment: this is my Post Method                                                                                      [HttpPost]  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails)//([FromBody]JObject json)
        {
          
            return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);

        }

Comment: this is how  i send the Request http://localhost:49290/api/config/Post?StartTimeDetails=[{%22ItemId%22:20,%22RegId%22:%22VISIT0001778%22,%22BLoadDetailId%22:%228/31/2018%2012:28:10%20PM%22,%22OrderReferenceNo%22:null,%22StartTime%22:%220001-01-01T00:00:00%22,%22InvalidItemMsg%22:%22%22,%22InvalidItemstatus%22:false,%22BLoadingBay%22:%22Chute%20009%22,%22BLoadingBayCode%22:null,%22BLoadingBayID%22:7,%22RFID%22:7123,%22GangId%22:2,%22BOrderTransfer%22:false,%22BLoadedBags%22:0.0,%22BRemainingBags%22:0.0,%22BConversionValue%22:null,%22WHid%22:2}]

Comment: oh did u hit it like query parameters. do you want your json to be pass like above to web api?

Comment: the url you shown is actually a `Get` request to web api not post, you have to set `HttpGet` attribute to web api method

Comment: @ershoaib : yes. if am wrong, Please correct me.

Comment: Ok I'll add answer for you to clear you about `Get` and `Post` method

Comment: @ershoaib: ur correct, but i want to insert those json data to sql server,how could i perform that, and check the Post method is assigned with the list details

Comment: this is actually a 'Get' method so modify your method like `[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage MyGet(string StartTimeDetails)
        {
            List<clsStartTimeUpdate> clsStartTimeUpdates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clsStartTimeUpdate>>(StartTimeDetails);
            return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);
        }`

Comment: and change your url from  `localhost:49290/api/config/Post?StartTimeDetails=` to `localhost:49290/api/config/MyGet?StartTimeDetails=` and remaining data will remains same

Comment: @ershoaib : it works Perfectly, I couldn't thank you enough.. Thanks alot,ur genius

Comment: can i add this is as answer?

Comment: yes certainly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to convey your json with `HttpGet` request instead of `HttpPost` then you can follow below,

> ***1) Send Json with HttpGet***

**Method:** `Get`

**Url:**  `http://localhost:49290/api/config/MyGet?StartTimeDetails=[{%22ItemId%22:20,%22RegId%22:%22VISIT0001778%22,%22BLoadDetailId%22:%228/31/2018%2012:28:10%20PM%22,%22OrderReferenceNo%22:null,%22StartTime%22:%220001-01-01T00:00:00%22,%22InvalidItemMsg%22:%22%22,%22InvalidItemstatus%22:false,%22BLoadingBay%22:%22Chute%20009%22,%22BLoadingBayCode%22:null,%22BLoadingBayID%22:7,%22RFID%22:7123,%22GangId%22:2,%22BOrderTransfer%22:false,%22BLoadedBags%22:0.0,%22BRemainingBags%22:0.0,%22BConversionValue%22:null,%22WHid%22:2}]`

**Web Api Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage MyGet(string StartTimeDetails)
{
    List<clsStartTimeUpdate> clsStartTimeUpdates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clsStartTimeUpdate>>(StartTimeDetails);
    return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);
}
```

**Note:** Its bad practice to send huge json in query string, so for use HttpPost instead

> ***2) Send Json with HttpPost***

**Method**: `Post`

**Url:** `http://localhost:49290/api/config/MyPost`

**Data:**

```
[  
   {  
      "ItemId":20,
      "RegId":"VISIT0001778",
      "BLoadDetailId":"8/31/2018 12:28:10 PM",
      "OrderReferenceNo":null,
      "StartTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "InvalidItemMsg":"",
      "InvalidItemstatus":false,
      "BLoadingBay":"Chute 009",
      "BLoadingBayCode":null,
      "BLoadingBayID":7,
      "RFID":7123,
      "GangId":2,
      "BOrderTransfer":false,
      "BLoadedBags":0.0,
      "BRemainingBags":0.0,
      "BConversionValue":null,
      "WHid":2
   }
]
```

**Web Api Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage MyPost([FromBody]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails)
{
    return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);
}
```

Comment: @Udk, view the answer might be it help you and if then accept answer and vote up by clicking up arrow to answer :)

Comment: @Udk, Is anything wrong with my answer that you unaccepted it.? let me know, I'll try to resolve your problem :)

Comment: glad to see you have get rid from your problem and my answer help you :)

Comment: No, it was correct. am not sure with the usage of components for upvoting.hope it was OK now.

Answer (score 3):

For complex types Always use [FromBody] in the argument.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails)
{          
    return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);

}
```

And then specify your query object in Body.

Note: To specify the value in the body, You will need an API client like Postman or Swagger.
https://www.getpostman.com/

In Postman,

Select Post method and specify the URL,
Then go to "Body" tab and select raw.
Specify JSON as type.
In the body, paste your data.

```
   { [
     {
        "ItemId":20,
        ..........
     }
    ]}
```

[image]

The Other answer by @ershoaib is the real fix for the problem that OP is facing. However, I am leaving this answer as it is the standard which should be followed.

Comment: I did use the [FromBody] but the List assign                                                 
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]List<clsStartTimeUpdate> StartTimeDetails) to null, and how to specify query object in the body. can you please provide an example?

Comment: Are you using swagger or postman as a client for query, or what is your client for

Comment: Consider installing postman in your chrome. And then run a query. There you will get an option to pass the body.

Comment: I use Postman to view the Request details and errors and never did run a query, i was going through the example,but not sure that way of running the query. can you please advise with that also.

Comment: remove the json letter from my answer

Comment: @CodeNameJack, remove that query string parameter from url it doesn't mean anything

Comment: true that, also JSON format is a bit wrong, I have not executed the code anyways.

Comment: sorry I was lost forgot its a list, It was correct, I verified it can be taken as valid answer now.

Comment: @CodeNameJack : when i try to Post as advised i was returning 500 error. Could you please help me with that as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511920/how-to-call-the-post-method-in-api-which-includes-a-class-content

Comment: @ershoaib : could you suggest me a solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511920/how-to-call-the-post-method-in-api-which-includes-a-class-content as well, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using post you should expect the data in the controller method to come from body. See related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559813/calling-post-method-from-api-controller)