# Exception in Json response when Submitting to webapi from WP8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I'm having issue when i try to send data to Web api which gives an exception 
**HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**

System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d(Object sendState) at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object sendState)

at response
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(url, Isexist, jsontalleyHeader.ToString(), jsontalleydetail.ToString()));

Wp8 method

```
  public async Task<string> POSTtalleyDetails(bool Isexist, int count)
            { 
                string val = "";
                if ((Isexist == false))//first time Load started--need headerNo               
                {

                    try
                    {

                        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                        {



                            var valjsontalleyHeader = listRtnTalleySheetHeader;
                            var jsontalleyHeader = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valjsontalleyHeader);

                            var valtalleydetail = listRtnTalleySheetDetail;
                            var jsontalleydetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valtalleydetail);


                            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service:Port");
                            var url = "api/config/InsertTalleydetail?Isexist={0}&talleyheaderlist={1}&talleydetails={2}";
                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(url, Isexist, jsontalleyHeader.ToString(), jsontalleydetail.ToString()));

                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                val = "Ok";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                val = "No";                  
                            }

                        }

                        return val;

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        ex.ToString(); return val = "No";
                    }

                    //
                }
}
```

where jsontalleydetail will be

```
[{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"39.0D39.053000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:53.7504239+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":1,"_HattiQty":5,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"40.0D40.053000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:53.8672939+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":2,"_HattiQty":1,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"41.0D41.054000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.0238698+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":3,"_HattiQty":2,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"42.0D42.054000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.1564773+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":4,"_HattiQty":5,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"43.0D43.054000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.2542986+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":5,"_HattiQty":2,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"44.0D44.054000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.3582527+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":6,"_HattiQty":1,"_HattiWeight":0},{"_Isedited":true,"_CreatedBy":"tc1","_visitID":"VISIT0001783","_Remark":"","_Syncable":true,"_ID":"VISIT0001783","_ItemName":"Aeroplane (M) Flour 50Kg","_TalleySheetDetailNo":"45.0D45.054000","_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_ItemMasterId":33,"_WareHouseId":2,"_ManufacturedDate":"2018-09-25T00:00:00+05:30","_LoadingTypeId":7,"_LoadingDate":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.4742785+05:30","_ConfirmedHatti":7,"_HattiId":7,"_HattiQty":2,"_HattiWeight":0}]
```

and 
jsontalleyHeader will be

```
 [{"_Remark":"","_TsStartTime":"2018-09-25T16:51:54.4742785+05:30","_TsEndDatetime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","_VisitID":"VISIT0001783","_Approxweight":18.0,"_WHId":2,"_TalleySheetHeaderNo":"T2H1.033000","_Isedited":false,"_CreatedBy":null,"_visitID":null,"_Syncable":false,"_ID":null,"_ItemName":null,"_TalleySheetDetailNo":null,"_ItemMasterId":0,"_WareHouseId":0,"_ManufacturedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","_LoadingTypeId":null,"_LoadingDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","_ConfirmedHatti":null,"_HattiId":null,"_HattiQty":null,"_HattiWeight":0}]
```

my web api method is

```
 [HttpPost]         
      public HttpResponseMessage InsertTalleydetail([FromBody]List<clsTalleySheetHeader> talleyheaderlist, List<clsTalleySheetDetail>talleydetails)
            {
                return todoService.InsertTalleydetail(talleyheaderlist, talleydetails);
                    //base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, StartTimeDetails);
            }
```

I beleive this is because due to the data Load, because its work fine with 2 to 3 jsontalleydetail .

if could someone could advise me with regard to this , it will be a big help.

I was answered to similar question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202989/json-value-doesnt-assign-to-the-list-httppost`

Comment: Post the *entire* exception, not just parts of it.

Comment: BTW you are using `GET` to talk to a `POST` action. I'd bet the server returned a 404 because it couldn't find any such action. Use `PostAsync` instead

Comment: Inner exception is : System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}    Message : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Comment: Not the inner exception. Post the *full* exception. You posted only part of the call stack, not even the actual exception name and message. In any case, you are using GET when you should be using POST. That's never going to work

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Further , when i try to add   PostAsync,      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format(url, Isexist, jsontalleyHeader.ToString(), jsontalleydetail.ToString())); this gives me an Error : No overload for method 'PostAsync' takes 1 arguments, could you please guide me with how to add  jsontalleyHeader ,jsontalleydetail to the PostAsync

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :Exception  Message  is Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Comment: This Exception is solved , as per the rcommendation of @PanagiotisKanavos as i add "PostAsync ". Thank You