# How to Call,the POST method in API which includes a class Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

when i run the client code it gives me a 500 error.Since am still new to web api subject , I really appreciate the help, to identify where was my mistake.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    ObjHeader.listRtnTalleySheetHeader = lstRtnTalleySheetHeader;
    ObjHeader.listRtnTalleySheetDetail = lstRtnTalleySheetDetail;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://---service---");
    var url = "api/config/InsertTalleydetail/";
    var alldetails = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjHeader);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(alldetails, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        val = "Ok";
    else
        val = "No";
}
return val;
```

which the ObjHeader is    `clsAllTalleyHeaderDetail ObjHeader = new clsAllTalleyHeaderDetail();`
clsAllTalleyHeaderDetail is

```
public class clsAllTalleyHeaderDetail
    {
        public ObservableCollection<clsTalleySheetHeader> listRtnTalleySheetHeader { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<clsTalleySheetDetail> listRtnTalleySheetDetail { get; set; }

    }
```

then my WEb API

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage InsertTalleydetail([FromBody] clsAllTalleyHeaderDetail obj)
         {
                return   todoService.InsertTalleydetail(obj.listRtnTalleySheetHeader , obj.listRtnTalleySheetDetail );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For your main api you have to set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in `HttpClient` like

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type","application/json");
```

2) For your sample api you have to set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in postman with your `raw` format.

Comment: @Udk, view the answer might be it help you, mark it as accepted and vote up by clicking up arrow to anwer :)

Comment: @Udk, does the answer not satisfied you? Let me know if you faced any problem :)

Comment: definitely , another thing to be added. i have removed [Frombody]from web api controller as suggested . and i believe it does work  in mvc web  client call and in android. because in my case client call was made by windows phone with the [Frombody] it didnot work. plz correct me if i'am wrong.

Comment: Sure, I'll let u know about this. Currently m out of my office.